# Error when trying to use json_normalize to flatten nested dictionaries from dataframe (ERROR: string indices must be integers)

Tags: python, json, nested, json-normalize

Total beginner here trying to hack my way through a project.

Goal: create a data table of odds given by various sportsbooks for college football games

Problem: After I called the API and converted to a dataframe I discovered the column for the odds contains a nested list of dictionaries. Sample value:

```
[{'key': 'fanduel', 'title': 'FanDuel', 'last_update': '2022-12-09T06:41:42Z', 'markets': 
    [{'key': 'spreads', 'outcomes': 
        [{'name': 'Army Black Knights', 'price': -108, 'point': 2.5}, {'name': 'Navy Midshipmen', 'price': -112, 'point': -2.5}]}]}, 
 {'key': 'williamhill_us', 'title': 'William Hill (US)', 'last_update': '2022-12-09T06:41:22Z', 'markets': 
    [{'key': 'spreads', 'outcomes': 
        [{'name': 'Army Black Knights', 'price': -110, 'point': 2.5}, {'name': 'Navy Midshipmen', 'price': -110, 'point': -2.5}]}]},
```

When I try to use json_normalize I get the error: "string indices must be integers"

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

odds = requests.get(" https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/americanfootball_ncaaf/odds/?apiKey=___(user key)__&regions=us&markets=spreads,spreads&oddsFormat=american")

odds_df = pd.read_json(odds.text)

odds_df.head()

#excluding non-needed columns in this example:

| id    | home_team | away_team | bookmakers
| 123   | Army      | Navy      | [{'key': 'fanduel', 'title': 'FanDuel', 'last_...
| 456   | UAB       | Miami (OH)| [{'key': 'barstool', 'title': 'Barstool Sports...


df = pd.json_normalize(odds_df,'bookmakers',['id', 'home_team', 'away_team'])
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
Expected outcome:
| id    | home_team | away_team | sportsbook    | last_update         | odds_type | home_point
| 123   | Army      | Navy      | fanduel       | 2022-12-09T06:41:42Z| spread    | 2.5
| 123   | Army      | Navy      | williamhill_us| 2022-12-09T06:41:22Z| spread    | 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
odds_df=odds_df.explode('bookmakers').reset_index(drop=True) #explode bookmarks col

#normalize bookmakers column and join odds_df. Because we need id, home_team eg. title is your sportsbook column here. if it si wrong change to key.
df = odds_df.join(pd.json_normalize(odds_df['bookmakers'],record_path=['markets'],meta=['title','last_update'],meta_prefix='_')).drop('bookmakers',axis=1).explode('outcomes').reset_index(drop=True)
df =df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('outcomes'))).drop_duplicates()

'''
|    |   id | home_team   | away_team   | key     | _title            | _last_update         | name               |   price |   point |
|---:|-----:|:------------|:------------|:--------|:------------------|:---------------------|:-------------------|--------:|--------:|
|  0 |  123 | Army        | Navy        | spreads | FanDuel           | 2022-12-09T06:41:42Z | Army Black Knights |    -108 |     2.5 |
|  1 |  123 | Army        | Navy        | spreads | FanDuel           | 2022-12-09T06:41:42Z | Navy Midshipmen    |    -112 |    -2.5 |
|  2 |  123 | Army        | Navy        | spreads | William Hill (US) | 2022-12-09T06:41:22Z | Army Black Knights |    -110 |     2.5 |
|  3 |  123 | Army        | Navy        | spreads | William Hill (US) | 2022-12-09T06:41:22Z | Navy Midshipmen    |    -110 |    -2.5 |
'''
```

Note: Your output unclear. Thats why i added full output.

Comment: Whoa! That did it! Thank you very much - now to spend a couple hours pulling apart your work and learning it for myself. Thank you!!

Comment: Accepting/upvoting is Stackoverflow synonym of Thanks. So please accept or upvote if answer worked for you. Also if there is something you do not understand, please leave a comment.

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to count. Beginner's curse.